# C++ : multiple namespaces inside a function

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am trying the below code, using multiple namespaces (changing namespaces) inside a function. I am not sure what is wrong, I am not even sure whether I can use like below, but did not find any contradicting evidence in my short browsing,  please let me know what is wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace standard_one
{
        int i = 10;
}

namespace standard_two
{
        int i = 40;
}


main()
{
        using namespace standard_one;
        cout << "value of i is " << i << endl;

        {
                using namespace standard_two;
                cout << "value of i after namespace change is " << i << endl; // Compilation error here, compiler is complaining that "i" is undeclared
        }
}
```

Comment: The most wrong thing is that `main` does not have a return type.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Yes, accepted, code hastily written just to illustrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not undeclared, it's ambiguous. Both `using` directives apply to the inner scope and so both `i`s were brought in the scope. Without fully qualifying the name, the compiler can't know which one you mean.

You can use fully qualified name and say either `standard_one::i` or `standard_two::i` to resolve the ambiguity.

Offtopic:

```
   int main() {
// ^^^ !!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this. it is scoped incorrectly

```
main()
{
        cout << "value of i is " << standard_one::i << endl;
        {
                cout << "value of i after namespace change is " << standard_two::i << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: o, and you can remove the { and } brackets after the first cout

Answer (score 0):

You must limit the scope of the `using namespace standard_one` statement, just like you limit `using namespace standard_two`.

```
int main()
{
        {
            using namespace standard_one;
            cout << "value of i is " << i << endl;
        }
        {
            using namespace standard_two;
            cout << "value of i after namespace change is " << i << endl; // Compilation error here, compiler is complaining that "i" is undeclared
        }
}
```

Also, don't forget to make `main()` return an `int`.